# use inner class as a generic parameter to HashMap

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

encountered a little .. tricky issues.  Saw many topic online walking about this, but not precisely getting where to turn
Here are the issue have a class A, defined in the file A.  And an inner class B defined in the same file A.

```
public class A implements Serializable{
... some code and fields.. etc
   class B implements Serializable{
   }
 ...
}
```

All that is defined in a module included in my project as a jar file ..
In a main project, I need to define a HashMap holding objects of type B.  So, altimately the goal is something like this...

```
HashMap<String, B> map = new HashMap<String, B>()
```

I know that B is not accessible from where I currently am, so I am trying to find a proper syntax to do it.
Tried this way:
    `HashMap<String, A.B> map = new HashMap<String, A.B>()`

But it compiler complains that B is not visible.
Can anyone help?  Is it a realistic problem?

Comment: Make class B public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to use `B` where it is not currently visible, you should probably make it visible declaring it `public`:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    // ...
    public class B implements Serializable {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make B a member of A and return B using a getter method. Ideally, you want to keep instance members private and use getter methods to access them. For instance

```
public class A {
 private B b;

 public A() {
  this.b = new B();
 }

 public B getB() {
  return this.B;
 }

 class B {

 }

}

B b = new A().getB();
```

Here is where it gets tricky; You can only declare one public class per java file, except it's an inner class. The second will be package-default. If you are in the same package, then you can declare a variable of type B. Else, you create a separate class file for B.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve a problem of using B as a generic parameter for HashMap element.The answer from @JeanLogeart did the trick.